# Parsing an XML file and collect the wanted value

Tags: wpf, xml-parsing

I try to Parse an XML file and collect from it the wanted value. I've the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<TDXItem>
    <PROJECT_NAME name="Project_MNG_Test">
            <PROJECT_ID>1022</PROJECT_ID>
            <DOMAIN_NAME>PROJECTS_MNG</DOMAIN_NAME>
            <DB_NAME>projects_mng_project_mng_test_</DB_NAME>
    </PROJECT_NAME>
    <PROJECT_NAME name="Project_MNG_Test1">
            <PROJECT_ID>1023</PROJECT_ID>
            <DOMAIN_NAME>PROJECTS_MNG</DOMAIN_NAME>
            <DB_NAME>projects_mng_project_mng_test1_</DB_NAME>
    </PROJECT_NAME>
</TDXItem>
```

and I tried versious of codes, most recent the below code:

```
public static void RunQuery(){
            string UserName = null;
            string xmlURI = "Sites_Name.xml";
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(xmlURI);
            var field = doc.Descendants("PROJECT_NAME").Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("name") == "PROJECT_MNG_Test").FirstOrDefault();
            if (field != null)
            {
        // Use value here                    
        string value = (string)field.Element("DB_NAME");

             }    
 }
```

but my value is getting null all the time, I tried a lot of convention noting work.
I know that it's my bad, but i don't know where, in my code or at the way I built the XML file.

Comment: TDXItem is not a namespace - it is the root of your document. This is why it's not working...

Comment: @Anthill so what can I do? change the XML? or the code? i tried to reference it without "ns" only "PROJECT_NAME" but no luck there.

Comment: @devdigital done :) 10x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't specify a namespace here, for example use:

```
var field = doc.Descendants("PROJECT_NAME")
   .Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("name") == "Project_MNG_Test").FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I tried it earlier, still getting null on value, as I told to Anthill.

Comment: Answer updated, you also need to change the attribute casing, as XML is case sensitive

Comment: the XML is generated from a system in my work so the casing is from there, and I used the same casing in the code(?!), but it's not working, still getting null.

Comment: No, that really does work, can you post your fully updated code?

Comment: You haven't changed the casing in the code above - PROJECT_MNG_Test should be Project_MNG_Test.